# How would you write a number in base 100?

Tags: number-systems

When `30(10) = 1E(16)` and `100(10) = 1a(64)`, what is the result of `199(10) = x(100)`?

Comment: What symbol do you use to represent $99$ in base $100$?

Comment: $36_{10}=1E_{16}$ ???

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Please provide some more details and background to your question and show your own efforts. Otherwise people may not be able to (or want to) help you.

Comment: Mars Plastic: I'm not sure what details would that be, could you be more specific please?

Comment: Yves Daoust: Thank you, I made a mistake. It should be 30(10) = 1E(16).

Comment: You do not need symbols. You can also write down the number in vector form , for example $[3,7,91,22]$ for $3\cdot 100^3+7\cdot 100^2+91\cdot 100+22$. PARI/GP for example uses this possibility.

Answer (score 4):

To write numbers in base $100$ you need $100$ different "digits", starting with $0$ and ending with whatever represents $99$. I would use the (base $10$) numbers $0, \ldots, 99$ for the digits, so, for example the number $12345$ (in base $10$) is $(1)(23)(45)$ in base $100$. You just group the ordinary digits in pairs, starting from the right.

So $199$ would be $(1)(99)$.

Comment: There is a precedent for this in ordinary life. Our timekeeping system of hours, minutes, and seconds is a base-sixty system inherited from the Babylonians. But we write the individual place values in that system (for example, the number of minutes) using two decimal digits.

Comment: David K: But then there's also precedent for using letters as a representation of numbers when writing numbers in hexadecimal...

Answer (score 2):

I think I'm the only one that does this, but what I do is use $[\dots ,cc, bb, aa]$ notation. For example

$12345_{10} = [1,23,45]_{100}$.

Comment: You are not. The author of PARI/GP does this as well , it would also be my way to write it down, but that might be a matter of taste. I wonder why this answer has a much worse score than the above one although it is an utterly equivalent method , just a little bit different written down (+1)